# Is there a way to modify Jersey generated XML response to include stylesheet info?

Tags: css, xml, rest, jersey

In JAXB, it's possible (using the marshaller object). I don't know how to do it using Jersey. I was wondering if there's a way I can somehow inject something like:

`<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="something.css"?>`

in the generated xml response.

Comment: How do you use Jersey and JAXB right now?

Comment: @Tichodroma I use it in configuration similar to one described in http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jersey-spring-integration-example/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See XmlHeader annotation. Attach that to your resource method. For example like this:

```
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@XmlHeader("<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/css\" href=\"something.css\"?>")
public JaxbBean getSomeXml() {
    ....
}
```