# JAX-RS/Jersey + text/xml : can I specify a xml-stylesheet?

Tags: java, xslt, jersey, jax-rs

I've implemented a REST service using [jersey](http://jersey.java.net/). When the mime-type for the response is "text/xml" is there a way to specify an associated [xml-stylesheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-stylesheet/) ?

Thank you.

update: here is a snippet of code:

```
@Path("/service")
@Stateless
public class MyServices
    {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "em")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Path("/id/{id}")
    @GET
    public MyClass getById(@PathParam("id")long id)
        {
        MyClass o=em.find(MyClass.class, id);
        return o;
        }
     }
```

.

```
@Entity(name="X")
@XmlRootElement(name="X")
@NamedQueries(...)
public class MyClass
    implements Serializable
    {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    ...
        }
```

Comment: Show us how your are publishing the Service (the method that you annotated with `@GET`, `@POST`) etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: [Is there a way to modify Jersey generated XML response to include stylesheet info?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218591/is-there-a-way-to-modify-jersey-generated-xml-response-to-include-stylesheet-inf)

There is a nice [XmlHeader](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/com/sun/jersey/api/provider/jaxb/XmlHeader.html) annotation that works well with JAXB.

```
@Path("/id/{id}")
@GET
@Produces("application/xml")
@XmlHeader("<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/css\" href=\"something.css\"?>")
public MyClass getById(@PathParam("id")long id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited with OPs comment:

I would use a StringWriter to first write the stylesheet information into it, and then marshal the object into it:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
//add processing instructions "by hand" with escaped quotation marks
//or single marks
writer.println("<?xml version='1.0'?>");
writer.println("<?xml-stylesheet type=\"text/xsl\" href=\"\">");

//create and configure marshaller to leave out processing instructions
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, Boolean.TRUE);

//marshal to the StringWriter
marshaller.marshal(someObject,writer);
//get the string representation 
String str = writer.toString();
```

Of course you can also directly print to every other output stream you want, e.g. files or Sytstem.out.

Put `<?xml-stylesheet href="my-style.css"?>` before the rest of your document?

Comment: my service returns an instance of a class that has been flagged with @XmlRootElement http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html . I don't (want to) manage the transformation to XML.